# Awesome nested set plugin - how to add new children to the tree at various levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a tree structure.. I am using Awesome nested set plugin. how to add nodes to the children at various levels. Please help me. I want to add ,edit and delete nodes at any levels.

Can anyone help me for the same?

Answer (score 3):

To add a children simply call

```
item.children.create(:name => "new item")
```

or

```
new_item = Item.new(:name => "new item")
item.children << new_item
```

You can find all the methods to manipulate the nested model at the plugin source code [1](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/master/lib/awesome_nested_set.rb)

http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/master/lib/awesome_nested_set.rb